# What is a reverse reference to the DOM object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this link: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/jquery-plugin-template/ it has a line of code that says

```
// Add a reverse reference to the DOM object
base.$el.data("yourPluginName", base);
```

what does the "reverse reference to the DOM object" mean?

Comment: I'm not really sure why they're even storing this reference to be honest, I'd start here if you're getting into plugins though: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you know the jQuery data function:

**It's storing a reference to the instance of the class in the data cache of jQuery, meaning that the stored instance *can be used to access* the initial `base` object *if it in the current context is not available*.**

This way, the class instance can be used later. **However**, the use of the `prototype` keyword upon the initial class that the instance were created from will modify the instance.

---

### **EDIT:**

Ooops, it seems that Anurag is right, and I was giving wrong information.
**Sorry**, the information I gave in initial answer was not completely correct. I've updated the answer, so it now tells the truth.
In the comments you're asking:

> so you mean its storing the current state of "base" in the data cache but if we make changes to "base" later on then the one in the data wont be affected? so if for some reason we needed to get the original one again we can do data('yourPluginName') to retrieve it? can you give me an example of when this would be helpful?

*It seems that none of the statements are correct.*

As I did obviously not remember adequately, the thing stored in `data` is only a reference to the object:

```
var obj = {};
obj.hello = "Hello";
$("#someElement").data("object", obj);
obj.world = " world.";
alert(
  obj.hello + 
  $("#someElement").data("object").world
); // alerts "Hello world."
```

BTW, JavaScript variables with names like this `base`-thing (but, more often seen as `that` or similar) are typically used to represent the current context, accessed through the `this` keyword, which on many occasions is more easy to store in another variable due to scoping/context changes, that will make the current context and therefore `this`, change.

Also due to issues with context, the stored value in `data` could be used to access the specific object instance from another context (that is, when `this` represents something else), instead of the version of the `base` object that was continually used after a copy of it was stored.

I hope this answered you questions :D

Comment: +1 ... and Sune, I believe that you are correct; modifying the `prototype` of `yourPluginName` **will indeed** modify the stored object.

Comment: so you mean its storing the current state of "base" in the data cache but if we make changes to "base" later on then the one in the data wont be affected? so if for some reason we needed to get the original one again we can do data('yourPluginName') to retrieve it? can you give me an example of when this would be helpful?

Comment: data will store a reference to the object, and not a copy - see example http://jsfiddle.net/rSCzT/

Comment: I'm so confused... can you edit the above so I can tell which of the many explanations is right? Everything I read I'm like... ok... I get it, then... "sorry, the info you just read is not correct" :(

Comment: i am a bit confused as well. what i got from it is this... basically it stores a reference to the object. this could be used for making it global instead of inside the scope of a function. correct?

Comment: @Plynx and @chadley: Sorry for the cofusion. When I became aware of the mistake, I corrected the answer, so it now tells the truth. Before making this comment, I thus edited the "sorry" thing so it's more clear what the truth is.

Answer (score 0):

The technique and the problem it solves is general and not specific to jQuery plugins. There may be cases where a Javascript object corresponds to a DOM element, and wraps logic specific to that DOM element. This object might be interested in listening to events such as clicks that happen within that DOM element. The information we get in those callbacks is the element that triggered it, and not the associated object. You could use jQuery's `data` API or any type of map in general to retrieve the corresponding object, and do something with it.